# How to make custom _url helper in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got this

```
match '/news/:year/:id' => 'news#show', :as => :news
```

I want to use:

```
<%= link_to n.title, n %>
```

(which returns /news/n.id/current_news.id instead of /news/n.date.year/n.id)

I want to get rid of this:

```
<%= link_to n.title, news_url(n, :year => n.date.year) %>
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 5):

You can override the helper that generates the path

adding something like this to the NewsHelper module should do the trick:

```
def news_path(news)
    "/news/#{news.date.year}/#{news.id}"
end
```

then `<%= link_to n.title, n %>`  will give you the url you want for news objects

Comment: Its a valid approach in this special case, but it's not testable and it doesn't extend to places where URL helpers are used by directly injecting the rails routes helpers

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this in a helper file:

```
def custom_link_to(*args)
  name         = args[0]
  obj          = args[1]
  if obj.is_a?(News) # or whatever class you are using
    link_to(name, news_url(obj, :year => obj.date.year))
  else
    link_to(args)
  end
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<%= custom_link_to n.title, n %>
```

Or you could override the [link_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) helper method with some similar code.  I would prefer the custom_link_to method because it presents less chance of screwing up other `link_to` calls.  But if you do it right you could certainly get away with it.